# Why does strlen in a if statement behave oddly?

Tags: c++, c, implicit-conversion, unsigned, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char str[11]= "Hello World";
    if(-1 > strlen(str)){
        printf(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This if condition should always return false. But here it's not. 
But if I put `strlen(str)` value to another variable and compare with that, then it works as expected. 
What I am missing here? 
Is it compiler dependent or something?

Comment: `printf(str)`...hmmmm.

Comment: Your `str` is not null terminated, since you didn't leave enough space for the null.  So calling `strlen` on it runs off the end, which causes undefined behavior.  Calling `printf` on it is undefined too.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `strlen` returns an *unsigned* value (`size_t`).

Comment: Change to `const char str[12] = "Hello World"`, or better, `const char str[] = "Hello World"` and let the compiler figure out the size (it will include a terminating null in this case).

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: You are comparing a signed value with an unsigned value. This does not result in a mathematically correct answer.

Comment: Just change it to `if (-1 > static_cast<int>(std::strlen(str))) {`, assuming you fix `str[12]` problem.  Or use `std::string`, and make everything easier.

Comment: @Eljay: I prefer the transformation `if (0 > 1 + std::strlen(str))`. 6 of one and 1/2 dozen of the other I guess though.

Comment: Evidently a person new to `C` can too easily arouse the wrath of more experienced `C` programmers by simply  not looking at compiler warnings, and invoking UB in the example code posted.  Or are all the down clicks just mindless pile-it-on?  Seriously,  the message has been received by now.  A little more self-control on the down click trigger finger might be a good idea here.

Comment: @ryyker: Indeed. The question is clear enough to be answerable. There's compilable code in there too, and the actual and expected behaviour is well-documented.

Comment: @ryyker, I was using arduino and there was no warnings showing.

Comment: Sometimes I see a question that for all appearances would be a very typical one, asked by any new programmer, and when written well enough to to be answered in such a clear way, they are often up clicked as being useful to other new programmers.  But then occasionally, for whatever strange reason the mood of the blogosphere is pissy. I think you just happened to post your question on a pissy day.  It's a good question.  By the way, the suggestion to turn up your compiler warnings in prior comments is a good one.  If you have not already done that, look up how in your compiler documentation.

Comment: @Bathsheba - yes I agree. Very well said.  Chalk this one up to  temporary insanity brought on by those in isolation too long, having to wear little blue masks and not being able to visit with their favorite people. :)

Comment: @ryyker: Indeed. I can't complain as I'm holed up in my large house in the West Country of England. I can't resist plugging my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303920/winter-bash-2017-counting-down-page-whats-with-the-fence/303921#303921 It's only conjecture but I think voting tends to be more extreme on a Friday: up and down.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should prefer `std::string` to character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`strlen` returns an `unsigned` type.

That has the effect of converting `-1` to an `unsigned` type, which is a large number.

That number will be greater than the `strlen` result so program control reaches the `if` statement body.

If you assign the value of `strlen` to a variable of `signed` type, and compare using that, then the conversion of `-1` will not occur and the `if` statement will behave as you expect.

---

Note that technically the behaviour of your code is undefined, you need 12 elements for that string (for the `NUL` terminator), not 11, and `strlen` requires that `NUL` terminator in order to work properly. It's best to let the compiler do the counting, by writing

```
const char str[] = "Hello World";
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you quoted the corresponding rule for the _binary arithmetic conversions_ from the C standard, to help the OP answer these kind of questions on their own.

Comment: @RolandIllig: The multi-tagging prevents my doing that. I also had to be vague about the explicit exclusion of `NUL` in the example the OP presents for similar reasons: the rules of C and C++ differ in that respect.

Comment: It may prevent you, but not me. For C11, it's in section 6.3.1.8 of the standard.

Comment: @RolandIllig has right. Just because OP is abusing tags, doesn't mean you can't quote. BTW the provided code is C code.

Comment: 14 upvotes in about 2 hours. That should someone top. ;-)